# Help with integration of $(f+ig)(f''+ig'')=3(f'+ig')^2$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the differential equation $$(f+ig)(f''+ig'')=3(f'+ig')^2,$$ and the solution says that by integrating once you get $$f'+ig'=C(f+ig)^3,$$ and twice $(f+ig)^{−2}=D−Cu.$ I tried with partial integration, but it got me nowhere. Can someone suggest how to integrate the equation, so that I get the solution?

Comment: Is $i=\sqrt{-1}?$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $w=f+ig.$ Then write it as 
$$
\frac{w''}{w'}=\frac{3w'}{w}\\
\frac{(w')'}{w'}=\frac{3w'}{w}.$$

Comment: ...and simplify life by writing $w:=f+ig$.

Comment: Thank you. Everything clear now.